# How to run php script using batch file?

Tags: php, powershell, batch-file

I write few powershell commands for logoff user in logoff.php file and when I execute my code on browser it executed successfully but when I passed this file in batch file user didn't logoff.
Please guide me.

logoff.php :

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM rdc_info");

$mstrng = shell_exec("C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe  -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -InputFormat none -command query user < NUL");

//echo $mstrng;

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $string = (explode(" ",$mstrng));
    $key = array_search($row['user_name'], $string);
    if($row['user_name']==$string[$key]) {
        $userName = $row['user_name'];
        $active_user = shell_exec("C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe  -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -InputFormat none -command query session $userName < NUL");
        $user = substr($active_user,80);
        $array = explode(' ',trim($user));
        $new = array();
        foreach ($array as $item) {
            if (is_numeric($item)) { array_push($new, $item); 
        } 
    }

    $session_id = implode('',$new);
    $len= strlen($session_id);
    for($i =0; $i<$len ; $i++) {
        $sssiduser=  $session_id[$i];
        $check = shell_exec("C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe  -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -InputFormat none -command logoff $sssiduser < NUL");
    }
}
```

Batch file code :

```
@echo off
cd\
set path=C:\xampp\php;
cd "C:\xampp\htdocs"
cd "C:\xampp\htdocs\ldap
php logoff.php
exit
```

Comment: Any file running from shell should be executable first by chmod 775 so you should check that also check error.log to know what is the problem

Comment: Don't redefine the environment variable `%PATH%`, unless you're appending -- i.e. `set "PATH=%PATH%;c:\xampp\php"` or `path %PATH%;c:\xampp\php`.  Adding `setlocal` immediately after `@echo off` is also a good practice, and might help with troubleshooting without your having to close and reopen the console to undo whatever mutilations you've performed on your environment variables.

Comment: You're not running a [tag:powershell] script, only a command, so you do not need `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass`. Additionally `-InputFormat` accepts either `text` or `xml`, _(not `none`)_, so I'd also suggest removing that from your commands too. As for your batch file, can you not use three lines? **1.** `@Set "Path=%Path%;C:\xampp\php"`, **2.** `@CD /D "C:\xampp\htdocs\ldap"`, **3.** `@php "logoff.php"`; two lines? **1.** `@CD /D "C:\xampp\htdocs\ldap"`, **2.** `@"C:\xampp\php\php" "logoff.php"`; or even a single line only? `@Start /D "C:\xampp\htdocs\ldap" "C:\xampp\php\php" "logoff.php"`.

Comment: Thanks. Now its working